# jQuery append get result fails for XHTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, append

When I try to `append()` the XHTML result of a `$.get()` to a container element,

```
$.get("my-webservice", function(data){
    $("#some-container").append(data);
  });
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'e.ownerDocument')
```

I also tried:

```
$("#some-container").append($(data));
```

and get the same error. `load()` works fine, so I know the webservice is returning good data:

```
$("#some-container").load("my-webservice");
```

At the webservice end, if I encode the XHTML as a string  before returning to `$.get()`, everything works as expected. The [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) docs say it accepts a string, DOM Element, or jQuery object - I suspect I am getting something about that wrong. Any suggestions?

The webservice is just returning some simple bootstrap XHTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span5">Div stuff</div>
  <div class="span4">More div stuff</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your html?

Comment: `console.log(data)` - are you sure it's the DOM and not an object which contains a nested property you need to reference?

Comment: @AlienWebguy Yes, tried that, it looks fine in the log.

Comment: @wst, looks like document type mismatch, can you try `$("#some-container").append($($.parseXML(data)));`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Using `parseXML` I don't get the error, but the data is also not appended.

Comment: @wst, did you double-check that the XHTML markup returned by your web service is well-formed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery is trying to make its best guess as to the type of document being returned when you use the `$.get` function without specifying a `dataType`.  As the last parameter of the `$.get` function try adding 'html' to specify the `dataType`.  See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for more information.

```
$.get("my-webservice", function(data){
    $("#some-container").append(data);
}, 'html');
```

Comment: Maybe this should be a separate question, but my webservice is declaring itself as xhtml. Any idea why it's failing to auto-detect the dataType?

Comment: What you posted could be part of an HTML document, but it could also be XML so how can we expect jQuery to accurately determine which one it is?  Also, the documentation itself is saying that if you don't specify the dataType attribute it's making an _Intelligent Guess_.  Since it's a _guess_ there's no guarantee it'll be right. Be safe and specify the dataType because depending on what is returned by the server it could _guess_ correctly sometimes and sometimes not.  In response to the service declaring itself as xhtml, jQuery only has the request URL and the data returned to make a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the debug console suggested the browser saw the webservice output as a DOM object, I eventually realized that the content type was not being properly set. Either or both of these changes to the webservice results in jQuery guessing `dataType` correctly:

1. Set response content type to `text/html`
2. Output `<!DOCTYPE html>` before the response